# Bash: путь с пробелами в массиве

Tags: linux, bash

Есть массив с путями и цикл его переберающий ([песочница](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMaGhlMDFsMGpXSDg)):

```
paths=(
    "~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages"
    ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local
    ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages
)

for path in ${paths[@]}
do
    echo ${path}
done
```

Результат:

> ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed
>
> Packages
>
> /home/cg/root/.config/sublime-text-3/Local
>
> /home/cg/root/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages

В результате видно, что возникает проблема с пробелом в пути `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages` и `Packages` воспринимается как элемент массива.

**Как её можно исправить?**

Единственное, что пришло в голову, это экранировать пробел:

```
paths=(
   ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed\ Packages
    ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local
    ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages
)
```

Но результат тот же.

---

**P. S.** Если код в песочнице не работает, то нужно очистить куки; по крайней мере у меня возникали какие-то проблемы в Chrome с этим.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно поместить в двойные кавычки подстановку массива:

```
for path in "${paths[@]}"
```

---

да и при обращении к отдельным строкам двойные кавычки не помешают (чтобы опять-таки не столкнуться с разделением на подстроки по пробелам):

```
"${path}"
```

Comment: Пробовал `"${path}"`, но даже не думал, что `"${paths[@]}"` будет как-то влиять на происходящее в цикле.  `"${paths[@]}"` решает проблему. Спасибо.

Comment: for васпринимает пробел как показатель новых данных, экранирование ковычками должно стать привычкой, при написании скриптов.

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай приведу пример работающего кода

```
someArray=("Some string 1" "Some string 2")
    
for arrayItem in "${someArray[@]}"
do
echo "${arrayItem}"
done
```