# передача замудренного имени файла параметром к .desktop ярлыку

Tags: linux, desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=curl --form file=@%u http://192.168.117.129:65220/playuri
Name=Play on TV
Icon=tv
```

Сделал такую ссылку чтоб передать торент файл в телевизор. Но осталась проблема с файлами вроде

```
Люди Икс Тёмный Феникс Dark Phoenix (Саймон Кинберг Simon Kinberg) [2019, США, фантастика, боевик, приключения, BDRip-AVC] Du [rutracker-5772992].torrent
```

Пробовал двойные кавычки - не помогло.

через xdg-open получил ошибку курла

curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

Comment: попробуйте вывести вашу команду в отдельный скрипт: `Exec=script.sh %u` и в нём брать в кавычки: `curl --form file="$1" http://192.168.117.129:65220/playuri`

Comment: не прокатит. пробелы в имени. разве что через `$@` но как бы исправлять не создавая лишних файлов.

Comment: посмотрите, может этот ответ вам поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647412/bash-путь-с-пробелами-в-массиве

Comment: проблема в том как скормить имя файла с пробелами курлу

Comment: @eri проще действительно будет в скрипт обернуть... а `curl`'у просто скорми файл в `stdin` (`-F file=@-`)... и кстати, лучше использовать не `%u`, а `%f`...

Comment: %u и %f в данном случае показывают одно и тоже

Comment: @eri, это пока не попробуешь открыть файл напрямую с какой-нить самбы или `http`... в нормальных браузерах ЕМНИП такой фичи нет, а вот в `konqueror`'е под правой кнопкой мыши на ссылке будет менюшечка «открыть с помощью» и если в нём выбрать «Play on TV», то с `%u` `cat`'у передастся ссылка вместо файла... а с `%f` всё нормально обработается

Answer (score 1):

Запустил файл таким образом

```
Exec=bash -c "cat %f | curl -v --form file=@- http://192.168.117.129:65220/playuri"
```